# PHP callback equivalent

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the equivalent python code for this PHP code :

```
return $this->cache->get(
    sprintf('pokepedia.wikitext.pokemonmove.%s,%s.%s', $name, $generation, 'level'),
    function () use ($name, $generation) {
        return $this->moveClient->getPokemonMoves(
            $name,
            $generation,
            MoveSetHelper::LEVELING_UP_TYPE
        );
    }
);
```

Here the cache function is just a function taking a string as the first parameter and a callable as the second, then the function can execute my callable if the data is not present in the cache.

I'm having trouble on how to pass a lambda/closure with parameter (equivalent of use() in PHP) to a function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`use` is a peculiarity of PHP to explicitly close over outer variables, which is unnecessary in Python, because outer variables are already accessible as is in inner scopes. You just need something like:

```
return self.cache.get(
    f'pokepedia.wikitext.pokemonmove.{name}.{generation}.level',
    lambda: self.moveClient.getPokemonMoves(name, generation, MoveSetHelper.LEVELING_UP_TYPE)
)
```

If `name` and `generation` may change between the call to `cache.get` and the invokation of the callback, then you may want to bind those current values explicitly through the argument default-value mechanism:

```
return self.cache.get(
    ...,
    lambda name=name, generation=generation: self...(name, generation, ...)
)
```

Or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

return self.get.cache(
    ...,
    partial(self.moveClient.getPokemonMoves, name, generation, MoveSetHelper.LEVELING_UP_TYPE)
)
```